# createContext failed: EGL_SUCCESS

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, egl, rajawali

The log says

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: EGL_SUCCESS
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1193)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1184)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1034)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

when I try to use the Rajawali library on Android studio.
I found out that the problem must be device-capability-specific, because my app runs on other devices (Samsung Galaxy Tab 4, Nexus) but not on Sony Xperia LT30p. I have looked around and have only found [this](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/issues/128) thread talking about the same problem.
I thought it might be a problem of RAM or overflowing, so I disabled all background processes and uninstalled most apps. Still, the error persists.
Does anyone know why this happens and if there exists a way around it?

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because the config call order is wrong..

```
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

And the right order is:

```
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

But even using wrong order, the code is still correct in most of the phones.(I just met this error at a 4.2.1 phone)

Comment: The GLSurfaceView docs don't specify a correct call order for those two methods as far as I can tell - do you have a link to back up this answer?

Comment: @Karu No, I just tried it by myself and found the issue on the specific phone. So I do not know why.